# Parsing data obtained from Google DATA API

Tags: json, google-api

I am working on a Google API to obtain the contacts of users at my website, and I obtained a result using like this, but I wish wish to have the contacts out of the whole chunk.

I just wanna know , how can I parse values from here ??

Here is the data i received :-

> ```js
>    [0]=>   array(7) {
>     ["id"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       ["$t"]=>
>       string(83)
> "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/atiprashant%40gmail.com/base/1213ed0accdb4e"
>     }
>     ["updated"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       ["$t"]=>
>       string(24) "2011-07-16T06:04:00.610Z"
>     }
>     ["category"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       array(2) {
>         ["scheme"]=>
>         string(37) "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
>         ["term"]=>
>         string(46) "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
>       }
>     }
>     ["title"]=>
>     array(2) {
>       ["type"]=>
>       string(4) "text"
>       ["$t"]=>
>       string(22) "ajay kumar yadav RKite"
>     }
>     ["link"]=>
>     array(4) {
>       [0]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["rel"]=>
>         string(54)
> "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo"
>         ["type"]=>
>         string(7) "image/"
>         ["href"]=>
>         string(106)
> "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/atiprashant%40gmail.com/1213ed0accdb4e/18unp7AvcGYQW42p1HfLVA"
>       }
>       [1]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["rel"]=>
>         string(49) "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"
>         ["type"]=>
>         string(7) "image/"
>         ["href"]=>
>         string(83)
> "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/atiprashant%40gmail.com/1213ed0accdb4e"
>       }
>       [2]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["rel"]=>
>         string(4) "self"
>         ["type"]=>
>         string(20) "application/atom+xml"
>         ["href"]=>
>         string(84)
> "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/atiprashant%40gmail.com/full/1213ed0accdb4e"
>       }
>       [3]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["rel"]=>
>         string(4) "edit"
>         ["type"]=>
>         string(20) "application/atom+xml"
>         ["href"]=>
>         string(101)
> "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/atiprashant%40gmail.com/full/1213ed0accdb4e/1310796240610001"
>       }
>     }
>     ["gd$email"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["rel"]=>
>         string(38) "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
>         ["address"]=>
>         string(21) "ajay007iitk@gmail.com"
>         ["primary"]=>
>         string(4) "true"
>       }
>     }
>     ["gContact$groupMembershipInfo"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       array(2) {
>         ["deleted"]=>
>         string(5) "false"
>         ["href"]=>
>         string(83)
> "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/atiprashant%40gmail.com/base/3ba9061f0dded52e"
>       }
>     }   }
> ```

Comment: I wish to print lets say ajay007iitk@gmail.com, tell me the path to follow ???

Comment: Add more inffo to your question. What api are you using, what language are you using, wat kind of contact u wanna parse... this question is so vague

Comment: I am trying to obtain values from this form of data(JSON)

Comment: I am using pretty JSON http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#80339

Comment: Check it out urself at http://sillythingsthatmatter.in/myAPI/ReadyGetContact.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to parse it yourself. You can just use the Google Data library if it is available for your environment. For instance it has bindings for Java, .NET, PHP, GWT ([gwt-gdata](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gdata/)), Python, etc. Look at the following:

- http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/
- http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html

Comment: Sure, if you'd like to parse it yourself instead of use a library, go for it!

Comment: Finally I am done with it  http://sillythingsthatmatter.in/myAPI/authenticate.php

Comment: i got gData up but it doesnt have anything about parsing, where should i look?

Comment: @t q, the point is that you don't have to parse. The API let's you deal with the data in the programming language of your choice. For instance for the Contacts API, in Java you might look at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v2/developers_guide_java for ideas on how to get started. You still configure some URLs, but then interact with the service through code. Just click on the google project for the library for your language in the second link in my answer and you should find some documentation to get you going.